# ProgressBar for a function that has to communicate with QObjects

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt5, progress

My Plugin uploads Layers to a WebGIS and the QGIS GUI turns inactive during this process. So that the User knows that the Program hasn't crashed I want to implement a ProgressBar.

My first try gave me a black Window that only refreshes after the task was done. So I learned that I have to use threading. But I'm not sure if I should use threading provided by Python, PyQt or PyQGIS.

Also like the QGIS Documentations says I can't use data from the main task, so I'm not sure how to continue from here. All the tutorials I found, only build threads with `time.sleep` but I guess I need another depth of complexity.